# Generating Function of a Recurrence Relation.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

Given a sequence a(n) = a(n -2) , a(0) = 2 , a(1) = -1

Find the generating function

What i have done so far:

The recurrence relation is going to be a(n) - a(n-2) = 0

A = the generating function

A = 2 - x + 2x^2 - x^3 + 2x^4.......

x^2 * A = 2x^2 - x^3 + 2x^4 ..........

- subtracting the two equations.

1-x^2 A = 2 -x

 divide both sides by 1-x^2

A = 2-x / 1-x^2

This is how i was taught to do it , but when u plug in numbers for x , it doesnt seem to satisfy the premise.

Comment: Why are you plugging in numbers for $x$? What are you expecting to get back?

Comment: when you plug numbers for x , shouldnt it equal the a number in the sequence

Comment: No, except that $A(0)=a_0$.

Comment: Think about it: why on earth should $\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nk^n$ be equal to $a_k$?

Comment: so if i plug in say x=2 , its not suppose to equal a(2)?

Comment: Absolutely not. The generating function is not a closed form for the sequence; it’s a function whose power series has the terms of the sequence as coefficients.

Comment: Thank you , so did i solve for the correct generating function?

Comment: Yes, you did. I’ll write up a quick answer showing how you can reverse the process to check.

Comment: The series is a sum of two simple geometric progressions, or of a single one if you gather terms as in $(2-x)+(2-x)x^2_\cdots$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your generating function is correct. What you have to realize is that a generating function is not a closed form for the sequence: it’s a function whose power series has the terms of the sequence as coefficients.

Here you can actually work backwards to check that you have the right generating function. Split it into partial fractions:

$$A(x)=\frac{2-x}{1-x^2}=\frac{1/2}{1-x}+\frac{3/2}{1+x}\;.$$

You know that $$\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n\ge 0}x^n\;,$$

so (substituting $-x$ for $x$) $$\frac1{1+x}=\sum_{n\ge 0}(-x)^n=\sum_{n\ge 0}(-1)^nx^n\;,$$

and therefore

$$\begin{align*}
A(x)&=\frac12\sum_{n\ge 0}x^n+\frac32\sum_{n\ge 0}(-1)^nx^n\\\\
&=\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(\frac{1+3(-1)^n}2\right)x^n\;.
\end{align*}$$

You can easily check that

$$\frac{1+3(-1)^n}2=\begin{cases}
2,&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\
-1,&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\;.
\end{cases}$$